# Swift Core Data Predicate

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate

I want to filter Core Data using "NSPredicate" using relationship property value (each sublist has one origin list and each list has many sublists)

The sublist entity

```
@NSManaged public var addedDate: Date?
@NSManaged public var id: UUID?
@NSManaged public var index: Int16
@NSManaged public var title: String?
@NSManaged public var origin_List: ListOfTasks?   // its optional and I need to filter sublist using its id property
@NSManaged public var tasks: NSSet?
```

The List entity

```
@NSManaged public var id: UUID? // filter sublist using this id
@NSManaged public var index: Int16
@NSManaged public var title: String?
@NSManaged public var comments: NSSet?
@NSManaged public var groupSublists: NSSet?
@NSManaged public var origin_Group: ListOfTasks?
@NSManaged public var sublists: NSSet?   // The sublists
```

So I need to be sure the origin_list is not nil and for origin_list.id I have wrappedId then find if the id equal to specific id, In swift it will be like the following code

```
    if sublist.origin_List != nil && sublist.origin_List!.wrappedId == someId {
        // get all the matched sublists
    }
```

But I don't know how pass that to "NSPredicate"

Comment: I'm sorry for that it's just misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking for nil is done using "%K != nil" so the first part of the predicate would be

```
NSPredicate(format: "%K != nil", #keyPath(Sublist.origin_List))
```

(Replace `Sublist` with the actual name of that entity)

The second part would use a similar dot notation as in swift

```
NSPredicate(format: "%K = %@", 
            argumentArray: [#keyPath(Sublist.origin_List.id), someId])
```

This can then be put together into a compound predicate

```
NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [
        NSPredicate(format: "%K != nil", #keyPath(Sublist.origin_List)),
        NSPredicate(format: "%K = %@", 
                    argumentArray: [#keyPath(Sublist.origin_List.id), someId])
    ])
```

That being said you should first try with only the second predicate since I suspect the nil check is redundant in SQL. So hopefully the answer is simply

```
NSPredicate(format: "%K = %@", 
            argumentArray: [#keyPath(Sublist.origin_List.id), someId])
```

Comment: Side note, the `NSPredicate(format:argumentsArray:)` should avoid to write the cast `as! CVArg`: `NSPredicate(format: "%K = %@", argumentsArray: [#keyPath(Sublist.origin_List.id), someId])`

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @Larme, always good when we can avoid forced casting